# getting a xml namespace attribute in php

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, attributes

is it possible to get the `attribute:` `name="Total"` and the `value`?
I know it's possible in an array, but the row is not always the same.

**This is the XML:**

```
<XML>
<resultaten>
<resultaat>
<id>3123709</id>
<antwoord name="Total">9,0</antwoord>
<antwoord name="Communicatie">9,0</antwoord>
<antwoord name="Advies">9,0</antwoord>
<antwoord name="Deskundigheid">9,0</antwoord>
<antwoord name="Betrokkenheid">9,0</antwoord>
<antwoord name="Gemiddelde">9,0</antwoord>
</resultaat>
</resultaten>
</XML>
```

**And i tried this:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url)

$date = $xml->resultaten->resultaat->attributes();
echo $date;
```

Comment: that is simply an attribute rather than a namespace - but in essence yes, you can get that easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use `simplexml` so cannot advise on it's methods but using the standard `DOMDocument` and it's associated methods it is fairly trivial to get the `name` attribute values from the XML you show in the question.

```
$xml='<XML>
    <resultaten>
        <resultaat>
            <id>3123709</id>
            <antwoord name="Total">9,0</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Communicatie">9,0</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Advies">9,0</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Deskundigheid">9,0</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Betrokkenheid">9,0</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Gemiddelde">9,0</antwoord>
        </resultaat>
    </resultaten>
</XML>';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('antwoord');
foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->getAttribute('name') . '<br />';
```

outputs:

```
Total
Communicatie
Advies
Deskundigheid
Betrokkenheid
Gemiddelde
```

---

### update

To use a url as opposed to a string simply use the `load` method as below.

```
    $url='https://klantenvertellen.nl/xml/van_essen_advocaten';
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load( $url );
    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('antwoord');
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->getAttribute('name') . '<br />';
```

outputs:

```
datum
referentie
Uw voornaam/bedrijf:
Aanbeveling:
Geholpen door:
Ervaring:
Totaal oordeel
Communicatie
Advies
Deskun....etc
```

Comment: The problem is that i need the numbers and the xml is in a URL. The URL = "https://klantenvertellen.nl/xml/van_essen_advocaten"

Comment: `DOMDocument` has many methods - one of which is simply `load` which will load a url rather than a string

Comment: I get the picture, and with the nodeValue i get the value's. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use SimpleXML as you originally wanted is well - simple.  If you just want the Total value, then you can use XPath to say get the `antwoord` element with the `name` attribute which has a value of `Total`.  The `xpath()` call returns a list of matching elements, so use `[0]` to get the first one.  Also this returns a SimpleXMLElement, so to ensure the value is a string - cast it to `(string)` before using the value...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$total = $xml->xpath("//antwoord[@name='Total']")[0];
echo (string)$total;
```

gives...

```
9,0
```